# Is C++ (03) SFINAE aspect compiler independent?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, sfinae

I have a *header* file, whose functionality relies heavily on the *success* of SFINAE. In present `g++ 4.6` it works as expected. Should I assume that, my code will behave seamlessly in the same way for **all compilers** (C++03 compilers) ?

I find this as an issue, because if something differs it **won't** result in compiler error and silently would change the code flow.

Comment: All compilers since when?  "All" is quite large...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, edited I meant for C++03 conforming compilers.

Comment: I have the suspicion you mean a lot more than just SFINAE. Of course SFINAE is required to work. However, there may be areas where compiler support varies (partial specialization of member functions comes to mind)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you may rely on SFINAE to exist and function properly.

If you have a compiler that fails at it, then it's terminally non-conformant and all bets are off anyway.

Comment: Is there a 100% standard-compliant compiler without a bug? :P

Comment: It's a reasonable point, though. Exactly as we'd say, "SFINAE works except in terminally non-conformant compilers where all bets are off", we can say, "two-phase lookup works except in terminally non-conformant compilers where all bets are off". Unfortunately, many of us have to deal with TNCCWABAO: Visual C++. I think it's reasonable to ask, "is this one of those areas like two-phase lookup where a major compiler vendor can't get it working?". That's not what iammalind asked, he clarified "C++03 conforming", but perhaps not realizing how few conforming compilers exist. Ahem `export`.

Comment: @SteveJessop": The Non-Conformant Compiler Which Abuses Basically All Of everything"?

Comment: @Tomalak: yes, there's probably a taxonomy of non-conformance out there. Lacking `export` isn't so bad, at least GCC fails noisily if you try to use it. If iammilind has a case where lacking SFINAE silently changes the meaning of the program, then that is as bad as lacking two-phase lookup (which does the same). Although, I'd naively expect that *by definition* if SFINAE fails then you get an error -- the clue's in the name ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since it depends on the success of the SFINAE, you should use `static_assert` (or `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`) to make sure the SFINAE passed successfully.

I do not know if your code would work on **all** compilers, but the static assert would fail the compilation if a specific compiler fails to produce expected output for specific SFINAE.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `asserts` don't solve my problem. I want to know, if any C++03 conforming compiler, SFINAE is supposed to work exactly in a same way or not.